# how to fix getting 'invalid gem format' for every gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've been googling this for awhile. The most relevant post seems to be this:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/200151

I've updated gem to 1.3.5 and installed (from local) the rubygems-update-1.3.5.gem and then ran gem update --system. The update gem said it installed successfully and the gem update --system command returns with 'Nothing to update'. The link above suggests doing this with debug and verbose, which I've done, with the output below:

```
C:\InstantRails2-0\rails_apps\rftg>gem update --system --debug -V
Exception `NameError' at C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager
.rb:161 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::UpdateCommand
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827 - C
ould not find RubyGem test-unit (>= 0)

Updating RubyGems
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827 - R
ubyGem version error: sources(0.0.1 not > 0.0.1)

GET 200 OK: http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists
 - C:\Documents and Settings\prestonb/.gem/specs/gems.rubyforge.org%80
Nothing to update
```

I'm not sure what all that means. However, I did try to load from the gemcutter and s3.amazon and those are blocked (I'm behind a firewall).

Answer (score 0):

Can you install gem files locally (i.e., from a .gem file?) If you can, the problem is your network connection.

I don't understand what you mean by behind a firewall. Do you mean a proxy server? You may need to use the -p option on gem to point to your proxy server.

Comment: Yes, I can install gem files locally. This is at work and there is a firewall in place to block various sites. I doubt the IT support guys would give me the proxy server. At this point I'm tempted to blow away my entire ruby installation and start from scratch, if I knew I could get a clean install that was working. Recently I upgraded from 2.0.1 to 2.3.3 and have run into this 'a copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree'... error, and now because of this gem error it's difficult to change versions of rails.

Comment: So you can't browse to gemcutter.org? That's a problem... You'll have to remove any gem sources that aren't valid from your location.

Assuming you didn't remove the old version of Rails, you should be able to roll back by changing the rails version value in environment.rb.